# Does Windows 7 Starter support Bluetooth Personal Area Networks?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bluetooth, home-networking, pan

I know my two devices running Windows 10 support Bluetooth Personal Area Networks.

There are some differences between how some of the same functionality is accessed between Windows 7 and 10. I can't see the PAN feature in the same place on my Win 7 device as on my Win 10 devices.

I know Windows 7 starter lacked certain features but perhaps some features didn't arrive in any version of Windows 7 and only came with Windows 10.

And if Windows 7 doesn't have Bluetooth PAN support is there a way I can add it?

Comment: IIRC, Windows 7 does support it. Don’t know about Starter, though.

Comment: BlueTooth PAN support is based on hardware and drivers (I don't believe Windows versions is relevant for this, even Starter)... the standard Microsoft BT Drivers Stack do not support PAN, you would need the native BT Stack for your BT chipset like Widcomm/Broadcom, Toshiba, etc. The problem is after Windows Vista, most manufacturers stopped building their own drivers and just started using the Microsoft BT Driver stack. I know there was a question very similar to this a week or so ago with specific links to explain all this, but I just can't find it.